# Printing a matrix of structs and enums

Tags: c

this is my first post here so if i make any mistake please tell me.
So i'm making this mini game for my class and i need to create a matrix of n size (from input) that is filled with a struct of enums, the function that does that is `crea_scacchiera`.

when i want to print the matrix i pass to another function (stampa_scacchiera), i tried everything but i cant find a solution to **print the matrix without a segmentation fault**.

the minigame is divided in 3 files : main.c that only prints a menu, gamelib.h that defines the enums and structts, and gamelib.c where there is the function that creates and print the matrix.

i think the matrix is filled right, i just cant find a way to print it in the other function.

```c
//gamelib.h
extern void crea_mappa();
extern void gioca();
extern void termina_gioco();

enum Tipo_pericolo {nessun_pericolo, trappola, alieno} pericolo;
enum Stato_giocatore {vulnerabile, scudo_vita, solo_vita, solo_scudo};
enum Tipo_oggetto {nessun_oggetto, medikit, pozione, materiale, colpi_lanciarazzi} oggetto;






struct Giocatore
{
  enum Stato_giocatore stato;
  int Posizione_x;
  int Posizione_y;
  int zaino[4];
  int alieni_uccisi;

};

struct Cella
{
  enum Tipo_pericolo pericolo;
  enum Tipo_oggetto oggetto;


};
```

```c
//gamelib.c
#include "gamelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//penso ci vadano anche dichiarazioni di variabili
int n;
void crea_scacchiera();
void stampa_scacchiera(struct Cella *scacchiera);
struct Cella *scacchiera= NULL;
static struct Giocatore Ninja;
static struct Giocatore Ciccio;

void crea_mappa()
{
   int choice;

  do {
  printf("                  \n");
  printf("Sceglia cosa fare\n");
  printf("1} crea scacchiera\n");
  printf("2} stampa scacchiera\n");
  printf("3} termina creazione\n");
  printf("                    \n");
  scanf("%d",&choice );

  switch (choice) {
    case 1 :
            crea_scacchiera();
            break;


    case 2 :
            printf("stampa della scacchiera in corso\n");
            stampa_scacchiera(scacchiera);
            break;


    case 3 :
            printf("ritorno al menu della mappa\n");
            system("clear");
            break;
  }
}
while (choice!=3);


}


void gioca()
{
  printf("prova funzione, gioca\n");
}


void termina_gioco()
{
  printf("prova funzione, termina gioco\n" );
}

void crea_scacchiera()
{
//  enum Tipo_oggetto oggetto;
  //enum Tipo_pericolo pericolo;
  int i,j,rows,cols;
  extern  int n;
  //static int perc1,perc2,perc3,perc4,perc5,perc6,perc7,perc8;
   printf("                                       \n ");
   printf("inserisci la grandezza della scacchiera\n ");
   scanf("%d",&n);\
     rows=n;
     cols=n;
     scacchiera = (struct Cella *)malloc(rows* cols* sizeof(struct Cella));
     //int offset = i * cols + j;
      for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){


           scacchiera[i*cols+j].pericolo= trappola;




            scacchiera[i*cols+j].oggetto= pozione;


        }
      }

    Ninja.stato = solo_vita;
    Ninja.Posizione_x= rand()%n+1;
    Ninja.Posizione_y= rand()%n+1;
    Ciccio.stato = solo_vita;
    Ciccio.Posizione_x= rand()%n+1;
    Ciccio.Posizione_y= rand()%n+1;
    printf("%d\n",n );



}

 void stampa_scacchiera(struct Cella *scacchiera) //FuncB
{

int i,j,cols;
cols = n;
extern int n;
cols=n;

for (i=0; i<n; i++){
  for (j=0; j<n; j++){


  printf("oggetto scacchiera [%d] [%d] : %d\n",i,j,(scacchiera[i*cols+j]).oggetto );
  printf("pericolo scacchiera [%d] [%d] : %d\n",i,j,(scacchiera[i*cols+j]).pericolo );
 }
}


}
```

**I have modified the program now and this are the errors that is giving me**

```c
  gamelib.c:154:39: error: declaration of ‘scacchiera’ shadows a global declaration [-Werror=shadow]
  void stampa_scacchiera(struct Cella *scacchiera) //FuncB
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
gamelib.c:11:15: note: shadowed declaration is here
 struct Cella *scacchiera= NULL;
               ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `scacchiera` is local to the `crea_scacchiera` function. Perhaps it should be global, or you should return it?

Comment: Please notice too that Stack Overflow is not a tutoring website.

Comment: If you're using GCC, please compile with [`-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Werror` to have some errors to fix!](https://godbolt.org/z/3dM_OS)

Comment: `*scacchiera = (int *) ...` shouldn't compile cleanly, regardless of compiler settings.

Comment: I modified the program and these are the errors but i can't understand what i have to do to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has majorly serious issues:

1. **never** use your original language in code. **Always** write in english (variable names, function names and so on). Otherwise almost noone will bother.
2. don't use shortcut names like `crea_`. How much time did it save you not to type those two missing letters? While everyone else will look at this and wonder what `crea` is. Yea, sure, "everyone" knows, its shortcut from create. But not everyone is you, not everyone is master of english and even then it will take them additional time of their live to decipher your "style" (read: mess).
3. formatting matters. Otherwise once again almost noone will bother.
4. Try this:

   ```
    scacchiera = (struct Cella *)malloc(rows* cols* sizeof(struct Cella));
   ```

instead of

```
    int *scacchiera = (int *)malloc(rows* cols* sizeof(struct Cella));
```

You forgot to initialize your global variable.

5. After trying to assign to global variable your compiler barks on you, because types don't match. Try this:

   ```
   scacchiera = (struct Cella*)malloc(rows* cols* sizeof(struct Cella));
   ```
6. You also pass invalid value to printf (probably). Try this instead (removal of `&` operator). Otherwise you'll print address of a variable instead of it's value.

   ```
   printf("oggetto scacchiera [%d] [%d] : %d\n",i,j,(scacchiera[i*cols+j]).oggetto );
   printf("pericolo scacchiera [%d] [%d] : %d\n",i,j,(scacchiera[i*cols+j]).pericolo );
   ```

Comment: thank  you for the tips, sorry the name of the functions are in italian, next time i will use only english and sorry for the formatting and lack of comments but i'm  learning and this is a very big project form me and i'm a bit confused.

Comment: now it gives me erro on compilation :` gamelib.c:76:18: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct Cella’ from type ‘int *’
      *scacchiera = (int *)malloc(rows* cols* sizeof(struct Cella));
                  ^
gamelib.c:95:32: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct Cella’ from type ‘enum Tipo_pericolo’
            scacchiera[i*cols+j]= pericolo;
                                ^
gamelib.c:129:34: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct Cella’ from type ‘enum Tipo_oggetto’
             scacchiera[i*cols+j] = oggetto;`

Comment: Regarding point 2. actually `crea` stands for `create` in italian :D no shortcut there

Comment: ok i'm sorry for some really stupid errors, what do you mean about to initialize the global variable ?

Comment: @belloafigoa Basically all of your problems are caused by not passing around that variable correctly. All your functions should take it as parameter/return it. You should avoid using globals like the plague.

Comment: I've updated my answer. @Lundin is also correct, you should rewrite your code to pass that global variable as an argument.

Comment: Note: you need `scacchiera = (struct Cella *)` instead of `*scacchiera = (int *)` (note missing asterix on beginning).

Comment: so i have to return scacchiera from one function to another and erase the declaration outside of these function ?